# How to select nodes with conditions based on attributes

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I want to use XPath in XSLT to select nodes with conditions based on attribute values.

To illustrate my question, I have a short example XML instance like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150722_0" dateTime="2015-07-13T01:04:20+02:00"/>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-13T01:04:20+02:00"/>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-20T14:14:22+02:00"/>
</root>
```

And I want to select all `elementA` nodes with following conditions:

- the attribute `fID` is unique
- If there are multiple `elementA` nodes with the same `fID` attribute value, then only the one with newest `dateTime` will be selected.

So in my example I want to select the first and third `elementA`.

How can I achieve this with XPath 2.0 in XSLT 2.0?

Comment: You need to group and then sort groups, easy in XSLT 2.0? Do you use Saxon 9 or another XSLT 2.0 processor?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Yes, I use Saxon9.

Comment: @dingjun: Good question. One can select the wanted elements using a single Xpath 2.0 expression and no XSLT at all. This is way much simpler and shorter. See this in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is a pure, single and efficient (no sorting) XPath 2.0 expression**, which selects the wanted elements:

```
 for $fid in distinct-values(/*/*/@fID),
     $maxtime in  max(/*/*[@fID eq $fid]/@dateTime/xs:dateTime(.))
   return
     (/*/*[@fID eq $fid and xs:dateTime(@dateTime) eq $maxtime])[1]
```

**Here is a proof**, in which XSLT is used just to copy the result of evaluating the expression to the output:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
     "for $fid in distinct-values(/*/*/@fID),
          $maxtime in  max(/*/*[@fID eq $fid]/@dateTime/xs:dateTime(.))
        return
          (/*/*[@fID eq $fid and xs:dateTime(@dateTime) eq $maxtime])[1]
            "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When the above transformation is applied on this source XML document**:

```
<root>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150722_0" dateTime="2015-07-13T01:04:20+02:00"/>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-13T01:04:20+02:00"/>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-20T12:14:22+00:00"/>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-20T14:14:22+02:00"/>
    <elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-20T14:14:22+02:00"/>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<elementA fID="2013_4_20150722_0" dateTime="2015-07-13T01:04:20+02:00"/>
<elementA fID="2013_4_20150721_0" dateTime="2015-07-20T12:14:22+00:00"/>
```

**Note on efficiency**:

This XPath expression only uses the `max()` function, which is

> O(N)

-- better than the O(N*log(N)) of a solution that uses sorting.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your single XPath expression. It is great like your answers for other questions. For me the tricky part is `$maxtime in  max(/*/*[@fID eq $fid]/@dateTime/xs:dateTime(.))`

Comment: @dingjun, Yes, due to documenting flaw of the W3 XPath 2.0 Specification, very few people know that the last location step of a path expression can be a function -- this is hidden in the grammar rules. This is among one of the most powerful features of the language. Another peculiarity in the quoted sub-expression is that the right-hand-side of "in" is a single value. This is perfectly legal and substitutes the lack of a more general "let" expression, such as `let $var := value`, which can be found in XQuery and in XPath 3.0.

Comment: Yes, using a function in the last location step is new for me. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Here are the grammar rules mentioned by @dimitre-novatchev:  

`StepExpr ::= FilterExpr | AxisStep`,   

`FilterExpr ::= PrimaryExpr PredicateList`  ,

`PrimaryExpr ::= Literal | VarRef | ParenthesizedExpr | ContextItemExpr | FunctionCall`,  

`FunctionCall ::= QName "(" (ExprSingle ("," ExprSingle)*)? ")"`  

[http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#nt-bnf](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath20/#nt-bnf)

Answer (score 1):

I would do the grouping and sorting in XSLT 2.0, if you want to have that then available in XPath you could write a user-defined function wrapping the functionality:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:mf="http://example.com/mf"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs mf">

<xsl:output indent="yes"/>

<xsl:function name="mf:group-and-sort" as="element(elementA)*">
  <xsl:param name="input" as="element(elementA)*"/>
  <xsl:for-each-group select="$input" group-by="@fID">
    <xsl:variable name="sorted-group" as="element(elementA)*">
      <xsl:perform-sort select="current-group()">
        <xsl:sort select="xs:dateTime(@dateTime)" order="descending"/>
      </xsl:perform-sort>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:sequence select="$sorted-group[1]"/>
  </xsl:for-each-group>          
</xsl:function>

<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:variable name="max-elementAs" select="mf:group-and-sort(elementA)"/>
      <xsl:copy-of select="$max-elementAs"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Online example is at http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNb.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. It works as expected and the site  http://xsltransform.net is also awesome.

Comment: I tried to remove the part to define return type and parameter type `as="element(elementA)*"` in line 9 and line 10 in http://xsltransform.net/jyH9rNb . It will not make any difference. However when I remove `as="element(elementA)*"` in the line 12 `<xsl:variable name="sorted-group" as="element(elementA)*">` , then it will not return expected result. Can you please explain why?

Comment: See http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#variable-values and http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#temporary-trees, the way I have written the sample ensures that the original nodes in the input document are selected and returned, on the other hand, if you use `<xsl:variable name="varName">...</xsl:variable>`, a temporary tree fragment is created.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this explanation. 

When I don't provide `select` and `as` attribute, with `<xsl:variable>` I will get a document node back.

To get it work as expected when not providing `as="element(elementA)*"` for statement `<xsl:variable>`, I have to change the select attribute in `<xsl:sequence>` to `$sorted-group/elementA[1]` .

Comment: You can change the `select` as you said but the whole result is different, with my suggestion the function result and the value of the variable `max-elementAs` is a sequence of nodes from the primary input, with your changes the function returns and the variable contains copies of nodes from the primary input document. Of course if all you want is outputting those nodes to the result anyway then it does not matter, but if your original question on "How to select nodes..." is meant to select nodes in the input document then your changes result in not doing that, as explained.

Comment: Martin, I believe there is a simpler and shorter, pure XPath 2.0 solution :)

Comment: @MartinHonnen BTW, I believe you blog link in your user profile is not correct, the '_' should be replaced by '-' :)